# I'm trying to implement dark mode in react native

Tags: react-native, mobile, ios-darkmode, android-dark-theme

When trying to assign the variable "theme" (which receives the useColorScheme library) as a style, the following error is presented.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcCwk.jpg)

Light and dark styles were created in `styles.js`.

[Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/zehguilherme/a78fc54d4e444e8e00fe42e008976a0a)

[Github project](https://github.com/zehguilherme/semana-omnistack-11)

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useColorScheme` belongs to `'react-native-appearance'`, not `'react-native'`.

**Example**

```js
import { useColorScheme } from 'react-native-appearance'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, also noticing that if you try and import the Appearance component it comes in as null.

Using the simulator or Android emulator

Comment: I solved this error.

useColorScheme belongs to 'react-native-appearance', not 'react-native'.

It works both in the emulator and in the physical cell itself.